# Local Storage in javascript and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I have added some data in local storage in index.js file in javasrcipt using

```
var account = {
            name: name,
            email: email
            };
            //converts to JSON string the Object Literal
account = JSON.stringify(account);
localStorage.setItem('Account', account);
console.log("cookies"+localStorage.getItem('Account'));
```

my log returns me data saying cookies{"name":"Chetan shah" , "email":"some email id"}

Now I want to get this item to my controller.js in angularjs.I have used https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage this link

inside controller i wrote the below code

```
var classFinder= angular.module('classFinder',['onsen.directives', 'ngTouch','ngCookies','LocalStorageModule']);
classFinder.controller('courseController',['$scope', '$window', '$http', '$cookieStore','localStorageService',function($scope,$window,$http,$cookieStore,localStorageService){
var myaccount = localStorageService.get('Account');
console.log("cookiestore"+myaccount);
```

But my console return cookiestore null

How can i achieve the data from index.js to controller.js !!

Comment: have you considered using a service and the $rootscope.$broadcast function ?

Comment: nope i havent !!  How do i do that !!

Comment: What's the context of where you're storing to localStorage, and why not use localStorageServer instead of accessing localStorage directly?

Comment: the index.js file is coded in normal javascript and not angularjs

Comment: @MichalCharemza I dont know how to do that !! :( any example

Comment: oh okay then the broadcast might not be what you want when the index.js is coded in normal javascript

Comment: @Bongo are the local Storages different for normal Javascript and angularjs?? i mean when i store data using javascript to localstorage1 and fetch data in angularjs from localstorage2, are these localstorage1 and localstorage2 different??

Comment: i am not familiar with the angular local storage library could you maybe provide a plunker so that it is easier to see your approach ?

Comment: @Bongo http://plnkr.co/edit/4xFK3sl3UdLp8nY1ZhQx?p=preview

Comment: The answer provided by Michal charemza worked!! thanks for your time and support @Bongo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect what's happening is that the `localStorageService` is doing something in addition to just JSON encoding the value. Looking at the source https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage/blob/master/src/angular-local-storage.js , it seems to be at least adding a prefix of `ls` to the keys.

I would say you should use the same interface for setting the value as getting it so, either:

- Use window.localStorage directly in the controller (and I suspect you might need to decode the JSON as well):

  ```
  var classFinder= angular.module('classFinder',['onsen.directives', 'ngTouch','ngCookies','LocalStorageModule']);
  classFinder.controller('courseController',['$scope', '$window', '$http', '$cookieStore','localStorageService',function($scope,$window,$http,$cookieStore,localStorageService){
    var myaccount = $window.JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('Account'));
    console.log("cookiestore" + myaccount);
  ```
- or use the `localStorageService` to set the value from your index.js. If you need access to the context of the app, you can do this from `run` method:

  ```
  angular.module('classFinder').run(['localStorageService', function(localStorageService) {
    var account = {
      name: name,
      email: email
    };
    localStorageService.set('Account', account);
  });
  ```

  Note you will have to run the above *after* `angular.module('classFinder', [....])` so Angular knows its accessing a module that has already been created, rather than creating a new one. (Having the brackets / not having the brackets [ ] as the second argument to module makes all the difference)